# IBM MQ Uniform clustering in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-mq

I am running **IBM MQ 9.1.2.0 docker image in kubernetes** and trying to implement uniform clustering.

The following are the commands I am running:

First I am installing MQ using helm charts

```
helm install --name miraclemq ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 2.2.0 --set license=accept,service.type=LoadBalancer,persiste nce.useDynamicProvisioning=true,log.format=json,metrics.enabled=true,image.repository=ibmcom/mq,image.tag=9.1.2
```

I am getting an error when i run the command:

```
runmqsc -c QM1
```

error is given below

```
Loading of client module '/opt/mqm/lib64/libmqiz_r.so' failed
```

Comment: Is your runmqsc command in the same image as your queue manager? If so, does runmqsc without the -c (client connection) flag work?

Comment: Yes, The runmqsc command without the -c flag works, But I am writing a ccdt.json file and then exporting the .json file inside the mq container and then I am running the command
**runmqsc -c QM1**
So now I am getting the error 
**Loading of client module '/opt/mqm/lib64/libmqiz_r.so' failed**

Comment: Does the docker image you are using have the MQ Client installed in it? It would seem not.

Comment: The thing is I am trying to implement uniform clustering in MQ using kubernetes
The following are the commands I am running

First I am installing MQ using helm charts 
**helm install --name miraclemq ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 2.2.0 --set license=accept,service.type=LoadBalancer,persiste
nce.useDynamicProvisioning=true,log.format=json,metrics.enabled=true,image.repository=ibmcom/mq,image.tag=9.1.2**

Comment: Are you planning to run your clients in this image as well or from outside? You do not appear to have the MQ Client installed. The name of the package **ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev** suggests it is the server only and not the client. The error you are receiving tells you that the client is not installed.

Comment: Could you clarify in your question **WHERE** you are running the `runmqsc -c` command?

Comment: I am running this command **runmqsc -c** inside the docker container

Comment: I am trying this blog post
**https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2019/03/25/ibm-private-cloud-and-mqs-uniform-cluster/**

SO In this blog ..at **step 3** we are having Host ICP, can you tell me what is that host ICP

Also can you please suggest me on how to implement that blog post...I wast stuck at **Step 3**

Comment: If you want to run clients, and the `runmqsc -c` command, inside the docker container, then you need to get the MQ Client installed. "Host ICP" is "the IP address of the ICP host machine" according to the details underneath the JSON CCDT example in the blog post. [ICP = IBM Cloud Platform].

Comment: Can you tell me How to install the **MQ CLient** inside the docker container

Comment: I am running **three MQ pods** with **three queue managers** in my **kubernetes cluster** and In **step 2** I am creating a Loadbalancer for the mq pods, Now as **step 3** I am creating a JSON formated CCDT table and a json file consisting of 4 channels, one for load balancer and three pods and Now as **step 4** I need to provide the **HOST ICP value**, SO I need some clarity on what is the **Host ICP value in terms of kubernetes**, and what IP address value I need to provide in the **Host ICP, Is it a Pod IP or a Kubernetes Host IP** ?

Comment: This rather sounds like a separate question? The IP address you use in a CCDT entry is the target of that entry. if you are creating 4 channels, one for load balancer and one each for 3 pods, the IP address in the load balancer channel will be the IP address of the load balancer and the IP address for each pod channel will be the IP address of that pod.

Comment: I don't know enough about docker to know how to install things in it.

Comment: Also, earlier I was trying to glean why you needed the MQ client in your docker machine as it would be more likely that you would be connecting MQ clients into your docker machine from somewhere else. You didn't really answer that. Where are the clients running that are going to make use of this CCDT that you are creating? Can't you test the CCDT over there rather than in your docker machine?